# SQL Add more than 1 row with specific values

Tags: sql

I have a table MonthlyTransaction which contains 2 columns: paycode and Amount.
Each paycode has an amount for a specific ID in another table. I want to add 2 specific Amounts of paycodes 100 and 105 for the same ID. I also need them in the same row and don't want extra rows for each Value.

Here is the Query I wrote. The output is always 2 rows and if I delete the `WHERE` statement it will be more than 2 rows and will get all the paycodes for this specific ID.

```
SELECT
    EmpAssignment.EmployeeId,
    profile.NAME,
    Positions.PositionName,
    Nations.NationName,
    CASE
        WHEN(MonthlyTransaction.paycode=100) THEN MonthlyTransaction.Amount
    END AS BasicSalary,
    CASE
        WHEN(MonthlyTransaction.paycode=105) THEN MonthlyTransaction.Amount
    END AS HouseAllowance
--(BasicSalary+HouseAllowance) AS TotalAmount
FROM
    EmpAssignment 
LEFT JOIN PROFILE ON PROFILE.ProfileId = Empassignment.EmpId
LEFT JOIN Positions ON Positions.PositionNo = EmpAssignment.EmpId
LEFT JOIN Nations ON Nations.nationid = Empassignment.EmpId
LEFT JOIN MonthlyTransaction ON MonthlyTransaction.EmpId = Empassignment.EmpId
LEFT JOIN paycode ON paycode.code = MonthlyTransaction.Paycode
WHERE
    EmpAssignment.EmployeeId=102 AND
    (
        MonthlyTransaction.Paycode = 105 OR
        MonthlyTransaction.Paycode = 100
    )
GROUP BY
    EmpAssignment.EmployeeId,
    profile.NAME,
    Positions.PositionName,
    Nations.NationName,
    MonthlyTransaction.Paycode,
    MonthlyTransaction.Amount
ORDER BY
    EmployeeId ASC
```

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: can u help me to modify the query ?

Comment: Simply move `AND (MonthlyTransaction.Paycode = 105 OR MonthlyTransaction.Paycode = 100)` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause. (The one following `LEFT JOIN MonthlyTransaction`.)

Comment: @jarlh check this answer down

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT EmpAssignment.EmployeeId , profile.NAME , Positions.PositionName , Nations.NationName ,
    --CASE WHEN(MonthlyTransaction.paycode=100)THEN MonthlyTransaction.Amount END AS BasicSalary ,
    --CASE WHEN(MonthlyTransaction.paycode=105)THEN MonthlyTransaction.Amount END AS HouseAllowance
    MonthlyTransaction.Amount

    FROM EmpAssignment 
    INNER JOIN PROFILE ON PROFILE.ProfileId = Empassignment.EmpId
    LEFT JOIN Positions ON Positions.PositionNo = EmpAssignment.EmpId
    INNER JOIN Nations ON Nations.nationid = Empassignment.EmpId
    INNER JOIN MonthlyTransaction ON MonthlyTransaction.EmpId = Empassignment.EmpId
    INNER JOIN paycode ON paycode.code = MonthlyTransaction.Paycode

    WHERE EmpAssignment.EmployeeId=102 
    AND (MonthlyTransaction.Paycode = 105 OR MonthlyTransaction.Paycode = 100)

    GROUP BY EmpAssignment.EmployeeId , profile.NAME , Positions.PositionName , Nations.NationName ,
    MonthlyTransaction.Paycode,MonthlyTransaction.Amount
    ORDER BY EmployeeId ASC
```

@jarlh

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only joining to the table once (and getting all instances of either value). What you really want to do is join to the table twice (since you want two instances in each row returned) and have each join be on a separate value.

```
SELECT
    EA.EmployeeId,
    PR.NAME,
    POS.PositionName,
    N.NationName,
    BS.Amount AS BasicSalary,
    HA.Amount AS HouseAllowance
FROM
    EmpAssignment EA
LEFT JOIN PROFILE PR ON PR.ProfileId = EA.EmpId
LEFT JOIN Positions POS ON POS.PositionNo = EA.EmpId
LEFT JOIN Nations N ON N.nationid = EA.EmpId
LEFT JOIN MonthlyTransaction BS ON
    BS.EmpId = EA.EmpId AND
    BS.paycode = 100
LEFT JOIN MonthlyTransaction HA ON
    HA.EmpId = EA.EmpId AND
    HA.paycode = 105
WHERE
    EmpAssignment.EmployeeId=102
GROUP BY
    EA.EmployeeId,
    PR.NAME,
    POS.PositionName,
    N.NationName,
    BS.Amount,
    HA.Amount
ORDER BY
    EA.EmployeeId ASC
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'MonthlyTransaction.Amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please make sure that you have the latest version of code. I had to correct that. Thought that I got it before anyone could have grabbed the code, but maybe not. :)

Comment: see the answer below ... it is the final one ... but i have another issue if u can help ! ^_^

Comment: Yes, if you might get multiple rows of each type then you'll need to `SUM` the values. That's where having example data and expected output make questions much clearer.

Comment: Now I want to sum Basic Salary and House allowance ! do u have any idea how to make it ? with these 2 sum cases !!

Comment: Just do SUM(Amount) without any CASE statement. If you have any further questions, please create a new question for them as it's more difficult for others to find answers within comments and that's really not what the comment sections are for.

Comment: sum(Amount) -_- which one ... they both named Amount ! :D for each paycode ... I think u can't imagine the tables

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
    EmpAssignment.EmployeeId,
    profile.NAME,
    Positions.PositionName,
    Nations.NationName,
  SUM(  CASE
        WHEN(MonthlyTransaction.paycode=100) THEN MonthlyTransaction.Amount
    END) AS BasicSalary,
   SUM( CASE
        WHEN(MonthlyTransaction.paycode=105) THEN MonthlyTransaction.Amount
    END) AS HouseAllowance

FROM EmpAssignment 
LEFT JOIN PROFILE ON PROFILE.ProfileId = Empassignment.EmpId
LEFT JOIN Positions ON Positions.PositionNo = EmpAssignment.EmpId
LEFT JOIN Nations ON Nations.nationid = Empassignment.EmpId
LEFT JOIN MonthlyTransaction ON MonthlyTransaction.EmpId = Empassignment.EmpId
LEFT JOIN paycode ON paycode.code = MonthlyTransaction.Paycode
WHERE
    EmpAssignment.EmployeeId=102 AND
    (
        MonthlyTransaction.Paycode = 105 OR
        MonthlyTransaction.Paycode = 100
    )
GROUP BY
    EmpAssignment.EmployeeId,
    profile.NAME,
    Positions.PositionName,
    Nations.NationName
ORDER BY
    EmployeeId ASC
```

I want to sum Basic Salary and House allowance !